# Why is the shortcut to "select previous tab" not reliable in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, keyboard, bug, tabs

Quite frequently the shortcut to "select previous tab" in Safari does not trigger. Unfortunately, I've not been able to see a pattern of when this happens. Restarting Safari usually (always?) helps.

The shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>.

- How can  troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never experienced this in Safari, and I expect there is some sort of conflicting shortcut. Either that, or "quite frequently" your mouse focus is in Flash or Java, and shortcuts aren't being sent to the browser (which doesn't seem terribly likely given the frequency).

Due to having switched to Safari after several years in a row of using Chrome and Firefox, I've set the Previous/Next Tab commands to <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>, using System Preferences. Again, I've never had any issues with switching, so I'd suggest (if you're willing, and can't find the source of the problem) to set it to another shortcut you can remember.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try it and see how it goes...

Comment: Your assumption about flash was correct :) Damn you Adobe!

Comment: This is really weird: The standard shortcuts do not work sometimes due to flash. But the custom shortcuts always work.

Comment: Or to quote @jaberg: "Dear Adobe. Thanks for PostScript. Thanks for Photoshop 7. Thanks for PDF. Now please go away." http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38?m=3514241#3514241

Comment: If I had to guess about the custom shortcuts, it would be because whatever is seeing your keystrokes comes "in front" of Flash, because it overrides the default shortcuts. Just a guess though.